# Execute "static" method of a parent of a constructor accessed from a constructor array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance

Phew, even the question was hard to write. Here's the problem: I have a "game", more like a random simulator, which needs to choose a random action from an array of actions, like this one:

```
actions = [ Action1, Action2, Action3 ]
```

I have actions written as classes inheriting from the Action parent class:

```
function Action() {
    this.targets = [];
    this.used = [];
    this.execute = function(player) {
        doStuff();
        return whatever;
    };
}
//btw the below I've seen in a JS OOP tutorial but it doesn't work and I have to implement init() in every child action
Action.init = function(player) {
    var a = new this.constructor();
    return a.execute(player);
};
Action.checkRequirements = function() {
    return true;
};

Action1.prototype = new Action();
Action1.prototype.constructor = Action1;
function Action1 {
    this.execute = function(player) {
        doStuff();
        return whatever;
    }
}
Action1.init = function(player) {
    var a = new Action1();
    return a.execute(player);
}
```

So what I'm doing to execute an action and get its results is `var foo = actions.getRandomVal().init();` (getRandomVal is a simple custom script that returns a random value from the array) It works well, creates the object instance which properly inherits all properties and methods, executes the exec() method and returns its results... but now I have a `checkRequirements()` method which I want to implement in like 10% of the 100+ actions I wish to do, and I want it to simply be inherited from the Action class so that when it is not implemented in the child class it simply returns true and I don't have an idea how. If I do `var a = actions.getRandomVal();` and then `a.checkRequirements();` it throws an exception that a.checkRequirements is not a function.

PS: this is a relatively small non-profit project for a (large) group of friends, I don't need it to work in every browser, it needs to work in Chrome and I can just tell them to use Chrome for it.

Comment: `Action1.prototype = new Action();` is one of the reasons why [your OOP doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12592913/what-is-the-reason-to-use-the-new-keyword-here)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you only need to work with Chrome, I'd suggest to use ES6 `class` syntax which does all the inheritance properly, without the chance to mess up. This includes your `Action1` constructor to inherit properties ("static class members") from the `Action` constructor as you'd expect.

```
class Action {
    constructor() {
        this.targets = [];
        this.used = [];
    }
    execute(player) {
        doStuff();
        return whatever;
    }
    static init(player) {
        var a = new this(); // no .constructor
        return a.execute(player);
    }
    static checkRequirements() {
        return true;
    }
}

class Action1 {
    execute(player) {
        doOtherStuff();
        return whateverelse;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this works. I still don't know why the static methods weren't inherited when done the old way, but this is so much simpler and more elegant that I don't care.

Comment: @Deuxis Because in ES5, subclassing only did inheritance for the instances, not for the constructors (that hold the static properties).

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you're calling `checkRequirements()` on an instance:

```
a.checkRequirements();
```

But it's implemented statically:

```
Action.checkRequirements = function() {
    return true;
};
```

You probably want to bind this function to the prototype, so change the code above to this:

```
Action.prototype.checkRequirements = function() {
    return true;
};
```

Then when you want to override this in a derived type, like `Action1`, you can do this:

```
Action1.prototype.checkRequirements = function () {
    return (whatever);
}
```

As per comments, my guess is you want something like this...

```
// base Action type providing basic implementation
// Wrapped in an IIFE to prevent global scope pollution
// All functions are prototype bound to allow prototypical inheritance.
var Action = (function () {
    function Action() {
        this.targets = [];
        this.used = [];
    };

    Action.prototype.doStuff = function () {
        return;
    }

    Action.prototype.execute = function (player) {
        this.doStuff();
        return "whatever";
    }

    Action.prototype.checkRequirements = function () {
        return "foo";
    }

    return Action;
})();

var Action1 = (function () {
    Action1.prototype = new Action();
    Action1.prototype.constructor = Action1;

    function Action1() {
    }

    Action1.prototype.checkRequirements = function () {
        // Super call
        return Action.prototype.checkRequirements.call(this);
    }

    return Action1;
})();

var Action2 = (function () {
    Action2.prototype = new Action();
    Action2.prototype.constructor = Action2;

    function Action2() {
    }

    Action2.prototype.checkRequirements = function () {
        return "bar";
    }

    return Action2;
})();

// Set up array.
var array = [Action1, Action2];

// Create instances (this is where you would pick at random)
var a1 = new array[0]();
var a2 = new array[1]();
// var aofn = new array[rnd]();

// Tests
alert(a1.checkRequirements()); // Should "foo" because it called super (Action).
alert(a2.checkRequirements()); // Should "bar" because it's overridden.
```

**[Check it out on TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=%2F%2F%20base%20Action%20type%20providing%20basic%20implementation%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Wrapped%20in%20an%20IIFE%20to%20prevent%20global%20scope%20pollution%0D%0A%2F%2F%20All%20functions%20are%20prototype%20bound%20to%20allow%20prototypical%20inheritance.%0D%0Avar%20Action%20%3D%20(function%20()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20function%20Action()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.targets%20%3D%20%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.used%20%3D%20%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Action.prototype.doStuff%20%3D%20function%20()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Action.prototype.execute%20%3D%20function%20(player)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.doStuff()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%22whatever%22%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Action.prototype.checkRequirements%20%3D%20function%20()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%22foo%22%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20Action%3B%0D%0A%7D)()%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20Action1%20%3D%20(function%20()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Action1.prototype%20%3D%20new%20Action()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Action1.prototype.constructor%20%3D%20Action1%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20function%20Action1()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Action1.prototype.checkRequirements%20%3D%20function%20()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Super%20call%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20Action.prototype.checkRequirements.call(this)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20Action1%3B%0D%0A%7D)()%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20Action2%20%3D%20(function%20()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Action2.prototype%20%3D%20new%20Action()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Action2.prototype.constructor%20%3D%20Action2%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20function%20Action2()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Action2.prototype.checkRequirements%20%3D%20function%20()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%22bar%22%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20Action2%3B%0D%0A%7D)()%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Set%20up%20array.%0D%0Avar%20array%20%3D%20%5BAction1%2C%20Action2%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Create%20instances%20(this%20is%20where%20you%20would%20pick%20at%20random)%0D%0Avar%20a1%20%3D%20new%20array%5B0%5D()%3B%0D%0Avar%20a2%20%3D%20new%20array%5B1%5D()%3B%0D%0A%2F%2F%20var%20aofn%20%3D%20new%20array%5Brnd%5D()%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Tests%0D%0Aalert(a1.checkRequirements())%3B%20%2F%2F%20Should%20%22foo%22%20because%20it%20called%20super%20(Action).%0D%0Aalert(a2.checkRequirements())%3B%20%2F%2F%20Should%20%22bar%22%20because%20it's%20overridden.)**

Comment: This doesn't work, and there is no instance afaik, I never call `new` (and I don't even see **how** in the array situation). I'm choosing one from an array of classes and then calling its static method. It works if I implement the static `checkRequirements` in the child Action1 - it just doesn't get inherited from the parent Action. This is the same problem that made me implement `init()` in every child action even though it should be inherited from the parent. Oh well, I guess I'll just copy and paste `checkRequirements()` too. Leaving the question though, maybe someone will explain.

Comment: @Deuxis you are calling new from your `init()` function: `var a = new Action1();`. Let me update the answer...there will undoubtedly be an elegant solution.

Comment: @Deuxis out of curiosity, have you considered writing this with TypeScript first and seeing what the compiler produces?

Comment: @Deuxis see latest edit for alternative solution...or at least something to get you started.

Comment: Thank you for the help, but I first got frustrated and then used the class syntax from Bergi's answer because it's simpler and closer to my Java experience, and it worked, so I can't confirm or deny your answer. One thing though, I was calling init on randomly selected class - and that's exactly what wasn't working, I couldn't call the static method that should be inherited, had to define it for every child.